# Handle exceptions in Amqp.outboundAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using publisher confirms with Amqp.outboundAdapter, and I want to manage exception cases correctly.

According to the following adapter;

1. How can I catch network/connection failures
2. How can I catch exceptions which are thrown in ack, and nack channels?
3. How the timeout be configured for confirms?

// **code**

```
IntegrationFlows
                    .from("inputChannel")
                    .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
                            .confirmAckChannel(ackChannel())
                            .confirmNackChannel(nackChannel())
                    );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I catch network/connection failures

For that purpose you can add a *Request Handler Advice*, e.g. an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` or `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain

Or that one is just going to be thrown to the caller thread upstream, where you can handle it with the plain `try..catch` or an `errorChannel` if that is applicable for your flow.

> How can I catch exceptions which are thrown in ack, and nack channels?

These channels are starters for their specific flows. To avoid throwing exceptions into the `ConfirmCallback`, you should consider to make then as `QueueChannel` or an `ExecutorChannel`. This way you will do a thread shifting and those flows should have their own error handling. It could be the same way with a request handler advice chain or an `errorChannel`.

> How the timeout be configured for confirms?

Looks like there is no such an option like timeout for confirms to configure.
However you can expire them using `RabbitTemplate` API:

```
/**
 * Gets unconfirmed correlation data older than age and removes them.
 * @param age in milliseconds
 * @return the collection of correlation data for which confirms have
 * not been received or null if no such confirms exist.
 */
@Nullable
public Collection<CorrelationData> getUnconfirmed(long age) {
```